# Allowing temporary access to cpanel for freelancer

Tags: security, cpanel, shared-hosting

I'm currently using a2hosting's cpanel on a shared hosting account. I'd like to temporarly give access to a freelance developper so he can upload some php files, csv files and create tables in my database.

Does anyone know how I can do that? I'd like to be able to revoke their access after a few weeks.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't trust him/her, create an FTP account in the domain that is being worked on for the uploads.

Dev person should be able to create the database structure on their own machine and then dump it and give you a SQL file to recreate it on your server.

Comment: You can always create SQL user with restricted access if you can't be bothered with manually creating stuff for your developer.

Comment: @milo5b True, that is a reasonable solution, but I reckon if you don't trust your developer enough to give them access then you might want to lock them out completely

Comment: sure - I agree. However depending on what FTP access is given (and what process is used), he/she might need to have access to the DB password anyway.

Comment: yes we agree...I guess it is a matter for the person to determine what risk they are willing to take and then they have a number of options ranging from pretty much completely locked out to giving full access.

Comment: hi @Steve, the question above is happening to me also. Third party would like to setup turnkey website to my hosting. But my hosting has other web. So, giving them ftp access to specific folder would be enough, right? But if that's what I am doing, then they might can't setup the web properly. Am I right?